# blank screen on ubuntu server 14.04 on PC

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, screen

I am a new friend in linux / ubuntu social. I want install a ubuntu server 14.04 on my PC with below specification.

```
https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87C/specifications/
 - CPU intel core i7 3.5 
 - Motherboard ASUS z87-c with onboard graphic.
 - 16GB ram
 - 2 x 1TB HDD WD RAID 1 (Hardware Mirror)
```

I can install ubuntu server 14.04 successful, But after restart my PC, load the boot menu with many items:

- ubuntu
- ubuntu advanced
- ubuntu LTS
- ubuntu LTS advanced
- system setup

when I select ubuntu, after the showing many text, at finally below text repeating for me:

- incrementally starting raid arrays ...
- mdadm: create user root not found
- mdadm: create group disk not found

And after restart again, I can't see boot menu. I see only "Blank Screen" and can't type or any action on this page.
Create a boot-repair on my cooldisk and boot my PC with that. Then it, I upgrade my GRUB with boot-repair and you can see that result on below URL:

```
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14409112/
```

Could you help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installation time wrong *RAID configured*. 
Something wrong in your RAID configuration.
'So the grub can't find your boot drive. 
Your boot drive separate don't include into RAID. 
***I think you did the boot drive to RAID.***

> Reinstall, and fix the issue.

Read fully first [Installation guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes).

Comment: Hello Mahendra, Thank you for your response.
I reinstalled 100 times at 2 last week. when I install ubuntu, 2 times ask me about raid (intel and ata), and I accept (select yes) it.

Comment: Ok if you have issue with RAID, Try to LVM, Its will success for you.

Comment: excuse me for delay, I want have both (RAID and LVM). In step of Partitioning  in installation, I select LVM item, But I have this problem. Could you help me step by step in partition manager for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The problem is about Raid.
When I remove the Raid, My Ubuntu server loaded without any problem.
I have a new question about it, How can I have Ubuntu server 14.04 with Raid, Because without raid is unreasonable way.
I know boot drive should be without raid only, But I don't know how can do it.